# Why modal not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a modal but its not showing, and when i remove the bootstrap or class=modal it shows the info without the modal

usuarios.xhtml

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
                 </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts.js"></script>

        <div>
            <div class="container form-search">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <h:form id="formSearch">
                            <h:inputText value="#{searchMb.searchText}" id="save"
                                style="width: 80%;" />
                            <h:commandLink action="#{searchMb.searchUser()}"
                                styleClass="btn btn-info" value="Buscar Usuario">
                                <f:ajax render="listUsers" execute="formSearch"></f:ajax>
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </h:form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="listUsers">
                        <h5 style="margin-bottom: 30px;">#{searchMb.updateSearchUserText()}</h5>
                        <ul class="collection">
                            <ui:repeat var="user" value="#{searchMb.getUsersSearch()}">
                                <li style="position: relative"><a
                                    href="#modalsearch#{user.id_user}"
                                    onclick="openModalSearch(#{user.id_user})" class="black-text">
                                        <img width="100" height="100" src="#{authMb.getSrcImage(user)}"
                                        alt="" /> <strong class="title">#{user.username}</strong>
                                        <p>
                                            Seguidores: #{followMb.getFollowersByUser(user)} <br />
                                        </p>
                                </a>
                                    <div style="position: absolute; right: 5%; top: 30%;">
                                        <h:form style="display:inline;margin-left:10px;">
                                            <h:commandLink action="#{followMb.crearFollower(user)}"
                                                styleClass="#{followMb.getMessageFollow(user)}">
                                                <i>#{followMb.getIfExists(user)}</i>
                                                <f:ajax render="listUsers" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                        </h:form>

                                    </div></li>
                                <div id="modalsearch#{user.id_user}" class="modal">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <h3>Posts de #{user.username}</h3>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <ui:repeat var="post"
                                                value="#{createPostMb.getPostsByUser(user)}">
                                                <div >
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div>
                                                         <span>#{post.user.username}</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <p>#{post.content}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <p>#{post.date}hs</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </ui:repeat>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                            </ui:repeat>
                        </ul>
                        <br />

                    </h:panelGroup>
```

scripts.js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.modal').modal('show');
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  $('select').material_select();

});

function openModal(id) {
  $('#modal'+id).modal('open');
}

function openModalSearch(id) {
  $('#modalsearch'+id).modal('open');
}


$(function(){
  $('.form-seach form').on('keypress', function(event){
    if(event.which === 13 && $(event.target).is(':input')){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#save').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

When i erase the bootstrap.css the info shows. The modal never works the info yes, but  only when i remove the class=modal in the

Also i dont know if it is well called, i have it in my folder \src\main\webapp\js

Comment: Since you say that when you remove bootstrap.css it shows, so i don't think you have js issues but maybe some css is getting overriden. You need to use the developer tool, and check the html after showing the modal in both cases with bootstrap.css and without it and compare to see what is going on

Comment: $('.modal').modal('show'); ??

Comment: The info shows, the modal is never show. Also the info shows when i remove class=modal in the <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load your JS libraries (jquery and bootstrap) before your own Javascript. Since you're loading you `/js/scripts.js` before the libraries, you're making use of things that don't technically 'exist' yet.

Comment: Already change it, and the modal still not working. Maybe the Js is wrong?